# Independent Study of Mathematical Finance

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, finance

For the purpose of self-study, I am looking for an online course (lectures, exercises, solutions) that spans roughly the following topics:

- Stochastic integration
- Absence of arbitrage and martingale measures
- Fundamental theorem of asset pricing
- Option pricing and hedging
- Hedging duality
- Optimal investment problems

Preferably in continuous-time models. I have not been able to find a course on this subject that makes available lecture videos, exercises, and solutions.

**My questions:**

1. Are you aware of any such course that's available online and includes all course materials for self-study?
2. Do you have any other recommendations (literature or otherwise) for independent study of mathematical finance? I have a solid background in analysis, measure theory, and probability theory.

Comment: The Cambridge Part III course on Advanced Financial Models covers both the discrete and continuous time setting, as well as volatility models. It lacks the "hedging" you discuss, but hedging is often integral to any option pricing course (as it is priced as a hedge). Now this course is not available, but they use Baxter & Rennie Financial Calculus, Musiela & Rutkowski Martingale Methods in Financial Modelling and Shreve Stochastic Calculus for Finance.

Comment: Thank you, this is vey usful @Panda. If you want, you can write this as an answer and I will upvote it.